# How to add index to JSON bulk file to load in elasticsearch

Tags: json, elasticsearch

I have this JSON file and I wish to index it. How can i do it ?

```
{"type":"Feature","properties":{"MAPBLKLOT":"0001001","BLKLOT":"0001001","BLOCK_NUM":"0001","LOT_NUM":"001","FROM_ST":"0","TO_ST":"0","STREET":"UNKNOWN","ST_TYPE":null,"ODD_EVEN":"E"},"geometry":{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[-122.42200352825247,37.80848009696725,0],[-122.42207601332528,37.808835019815085,0],[-122.42110217434863,37.808803534992904,0],[-122.42106256906727,37.80860105681815,0],[-122.42200352825247,37.80848009696725,0]]]}}
```

Comment: First of all. It's an invalid JSON. Fix it/format it the way it's supposed to be. Provide more details and what you have tried so far/attempted to do.

Comment: This is the JSON file I have got. May you please show me valid sample of JSON file.

Comment: You can fix your JSON using [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com/). It will show what errors you have.

Comment: {"type":"Feature","properties":{"MAPBLKLOT":"0001001","BLKLOT":"0001001","BLOCK_NUM":"0001","LOT_NUM":"001","FROM_ST":"0","TO_ST":"0","STREET":"UNKNOWN","ST_TYPE":null,"ODD_EVEN":"E"},"geometry":{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[-122.42200352825247,37.80848009696725,0],[-122.42207601332528,37.808835019815085,0],[-122.42110217434863,37.808803534992904,0],[-122.42106256906727,37.80860105681815,0],[-122.42200352825247,37.80848009696725,0]]]}}

Comment: I have just added one line of JSON file.